# Jasmine vs Behat?

Tags: testing, jasmine, behat

We develop a web app, using next technologies: Symfony 2, Angular and Jenkins for CI. We believe, that Behat is great for testing API and Jasmine for testing the front-end. What should we use to test the front end part, according to Best Practice, Behat tests or Jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Jasmine, but Behat should be used to test your core features, if you need to test your FE, use a FE testing specific tool.

If you have some core features in your app that you need to test, and you need to interact with a browser, then use Behat + Goutte/Selenium. For example, in our shop, we have a Behat + Selenium test for the checkout process.